# PyInstaller Failed to Execute Script (pandas)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe

I've been using PyInstaller for a while now for work. Today I've been trying to compile a program for work using the same process I always do on the same program with some bug fixes - and the compile goes all the way through and builds. The final exe file gives me a weird error.

Same problem on my co-worker's computer. We also tried to use Py2Exe with no success.

What am I doing wrong? Any tips?

Screenshots - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkgaO.jpg

Comment: Please don't post error messages or code as a screenshot. Nobody wants to type anything from a picture and you limit the help you can get here on SO. Please edit your question.

Comment: Woot.. lets direct you [here where you learn How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and start editing your question. SO isn't a homework site and finish the tour ;-)

Comment: BTW.. be a little more specific in your question title as well. Lots of pandas.. in bamboo forest! Cheers in advance ;-)